# How can I remove the "No data available in data" in the DataTable?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web, datatable

I am trying to save this data to the DataTable when I have data from the database. But when I do this, the first line of the DataTable shows 'No data available in table'. This is because before the ajax form works, the datatable.js file works.( because of taking a long time the working of ajax form ). Namely  the system can not read any data in the DataTable in this way. Then when the ajax form run , my data is saved in the datatable, but the first line shows 'no data available in table'.And the datas is dysfunctional. So I can not press the update and delete buttons. Like this :
[image]

And my Ajax Code

```
var xGlobalTitle;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Home/postInformationofConferenceTitle',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {    
            xGlobalTitle = data.xglobalTitle;    
    }
}).done(function(data){
    $.post("/Home/selectRooms", { xtitle: xGlobalTitle }, function (data) {

            var ndx = 0;
            $.each(data.xroom_name, function (key, value) {

                var Xroom_name = data.xroom_name[ndx];
                var Xroom_plan = data.xroom_plan[ndx];

                var body = '<tr>';
                    body += '<td>' +
                    '<div class="img-container">' +
                    '<img src="../../assets/img/room-plan/' + Xroom_plan + '" alt="..." id="imgsrc">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</td>' ;
                    body += '<td id="imgname">' + Xroom_name + '</td>' ;
                    body += '<td class="text-right">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>' +
                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>' +
                    '</td>' ;
                    body += '</tr>';

                    $(body).appendTo($("tbody"));
                    $("#datatables").DataTable();
                ndx++;

            });


        });
});
```

The main thing is that I am using nested ajax form in here, so this code works at a time of n^2. And since it runs the dataTable.js script before completing this code run, the first line shows 'No data available in table'( Since this ajax codes takes a lot of time to work ).
How can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps... Right click on it on the browser window. Click Inspect Element. Find out if it has an ID. If it does, `$('#myID').empty();` after results are done loading.

Comment: Or... `$('#parentContainer').find('#targetContainer').empty();`

Comment: this is providing only remove the 'No data available in table'. But update and remove buttons still dont work because of  the system can not read any data in the DataTable. ( Since this ajax codes takes a lot of time to work )

Comment: Namely this ajax code takes a long time to work, so the script jquery.datatable.js is working first. And the data on this table is saved after 'NO DATA AVAILABLE IN TABLE'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample on event delegation for dynamically created elements.

See [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more details.

As you can see, this sample onclick event binds to elements that have already been created and elements that are yet to be added to the table.

Click on a table cell to trigger this event.

```js
$( "#dataTable tbody tr td" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log('Clicked target text: ' + $(this).text() );
});
```

```css
#dataTable {
width: 100%;
}

#dataTable thead {
text-align: left;
}

#dataTable tbody tr td {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Begin table -->
<table id="dataTable" class="striped col s12">

<!-- Begin table head -->
<thead>
<tr>
<th>DATE</th>
<th>CLIENT</th>
<th>TYPE</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<!-- ./ End table head -->

<!-- Begin table body -->
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2/21/18</td>
<td>CONNOR, SARAH</td>
<td>HOME</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2/21/17</td>
<td>TRAVOLTA, JOHN</td>
<td>HOME</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2/21/16</td>
<td>CRUISE, TOM</td>
<td>BUSINESS</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
<!-- ./ End table body -->

</table>
<!-- ./ End table -->
```